Azure Data Factory error when ingesting from Mysql
I try to ingest from on premise MySQL source using a Self-Hosted IR to an Azure SQL sink with Table Type defined using copy activity. The source Dataset previews the data fine but when debugging Copy Activity i get the following error:

Failure happened on 'Sink' side. ErrorCode=InvalidParameter,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The value of the property '' is invalid: 'The type of column 'id' is not supported.  The type is 'UInt64''.,Source=,''Type=System.ArgumentException,Message=The type of column 'id' is not supported.  The type is 'UInt64',Source=Microsoft.Data.SqlClient,'

The id column which is a primary key to the Mysql table its a bigint unassigned, and perhaps IR can't handle it. I defined the id column  as varchar, decimal etc on the Azure SQL table, to catch any type mismatch but still getting the same error, any suggestions?


Failure happened on 'Sink' side. ErrorCode=InvalidParameter,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The value of the property '' is invalid: 'The type of column 'id' is not supported. The type is 'UInt64''.,Source=,''Type=System.ArgumentException,Message=The type of column 'id' is not supported. The type is 'UInt64',Source=Microsoft.Data.SqlClient,'

The error you are encountering indicates that Azure Data Factory (ADF) IR is not able handle the UInt64 (BIGINT UNSIGNED in MySQL) type on the sink side. The root cause can be the mismatch between the MySQL BIGINT UNSIGNED and the supported data types in Azure SQL.

First you can try the updating the data type in Json payload of copy activity as belw:

"type": "String",
"physicalType": "varchar"


If this does not work you can need to change the datatype of source column in MySql table only to varchar or int type and then copy the data to Azure SQL after completion of copy activity you can again revert the datatype as previous.

If still issue persist, please raise the support ticket here

Thank you for the answer, editing the json mapping doesnt work, so I actually created a view with changed data type at the MySQL side in order to proceed. It seems there is a bug here.
